# Find the area enclosed by $f(x)=\frac{3e^{-x}}{1-3e^{-x}}$, $y=0$, $x=0$, $y=\ln2$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$f(x)=\frac{3e^{-x}}{1-3e^{-x}}, x \neq \ln3$$

Find the area enclosed by $f$, the $x$ and $y$ axes and the line $y=\ln2$.

How do I solve this question without the use of a calculator, since $f$ only tends towards the $x$ axis and never actually intercepts it?

Comment: Write $f(x)$ as $\frac{1}{\frac{e^x}{3}-1}$ and use $\int \frac{dx}{p+qe^{ax}}=\frac{x}{p}-\frac{1}{ap}\ln(p+qe^{ax})$

Comment: What are the limits of this integral? For this question of course.

Comment: Plot $\ln 2$ and $\frac{1}{\frac{e^x}{3}-1}$ into graph.tk.... can you work them out?

Comment: Tricky the limits are, is it not?

Comment: Equate f(x) to ln 2 and you will have ln3 in the limits which is not defined and that makes the problem interesting

Comment: @thesimplifire No use of external software or graphic calculators have been allowed for this question unfortunately.

Comment: You can try drawing rough sketches of the two functions on the same diagram by hand (diagrams always help in cases like this)

Comment: Yeah but the limits of the integral aren't exactly obtainable via that method are they? Especially since $f$ merely tends towards the $x$ axis and never intercepts it, and the intersection between $f$ and $ln2$ isn't very nice of an answer?

Comment: The other method I've thought of is finding the inverse function and integrating w.r.t $y$ instead but it isn't very nice of an answer either.

Comment: Maybe it is the line $x=\log 2$ otherwise the integral does not converge on $[0,\log 3)\cup(\log3,+\infty)$